# Adjust image size on individual product magento2

Tags: magento2

I have been trying to adjust the size of the main image in the individual product, what I am trying to do is make the red section cover the blue. I have already tried it with css but it does not work, apparently the base image keeps the measure of 700x700. I'm new to magento and I don't know if there is any function for this. I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to make this change, thanks.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqMCh.png)

Comment: Could you share you code block for this so that we can review

Answer (score 0):

You can change image size on etc/view.xml inside your themes directory, if your themes doesnt have any, you can copy from luma or blank theme (its under vendor/magento dir)

[image]

dont forget to flush cache after you change value of view.xml